# Maya: Bending a plane as a sphere passes over (space-time animation)

Tags: animation, maya

I’m a student using Maya for the first time to try make a ‘proof of concept’ for my future research work. I’m a newbie and I’ve been struggling to try figure this out, any help would be really appreciated:

I’m trying to animate an effect similar to the ‘space-time’ images you often see (fig 1). I’d like to have a plane, and when a sphere (planet) is animated over it the plane bends as shown in fig 1. I’ve gone through all the deformers in Maya and I just can’t see how to do this. I found iCollision, which can do something similar, but it's not quite right (it's more of a footprint than a curve on the plane). The soft manipulation deformer in Maya can make something like (Fig 2), which would work great, but I’m not sure if you can animate this (if I try, it just moves the apex of the deformation, not the whole deform along with the sphere). Ideally the deform ‘depth’  should be defined by the size or some other attribute of the sphere as it moves along.

Could anyone help or suggest how I can do this?

Thank you!

[Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12yNS.png)
[Fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T94Bm.png)

Comment: This is job for the [Sculpt deformer](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Sculpt-deformer-htm.html)   Just move the sculptor object and the origin object together to get the moving deformation.

However unless you're asking how to do it in script, it's not really a SO question

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Yes, the sculpt deformer did the trick! My apologies for the non-SO related question.